# How to add root and viewer queries on an existing GraphQL Server for Relay support

Tags: javascript, mongodb, graphql, relay

I've been working with GraphQL for a while and was able to successfully launch a simple GraphQL Server. Now I'm trying to make it support Relay, my final goal, and I'm having trouble adding support for the root node query and the viewer query.

I do understand the concept of both node and viewer, but I'm not making it work in the way I've structured my code. Here is my code, organized into separate files:

**./graphql/User/types.js**

```
import { 
    GraphQLObjectType, 
    GraphQLInputObjectType,
    GraphQLNonNull,
    GraphQLID,
    GraphQLList,
    GraphQLString, 
    GraphQLInt, 
    GraphQLBoolean 
} from 'graphql';

 import { GraphQLLong } from '../scalars';

 import { NodeInterface } from '../interfaces';

const fields = {
        _id: {
            type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLID)
        },
        email: {
            type: GraphQLString
        },
        firstName: {
            type: GraphQLString
        },
        lastName: {
            type: GraphQLString
        },
        jobTitle: {
            type: GraphQLString
        },
        phone: {
            type: GraphQLString
        }
    };


export const UserType = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'User',
    description: 'User',
    interface: NodeInterface,
    fields: fields
})
```

**./graphql/User/queries.js**

```
import { GraphQLNonNull, GraphQLID, GraphQLList } from 'graphql';

import { UserType, UserInputType } from './types';
import UserModel from '../../models/User';

const User = {
    type: UserType,
    description: 'Get single user',
    args: {
        id: {
            name: 'id',
            type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLID)
        }
    },
    resolve(root, params) {

        params.deleted = false;

        return UserModel.find(params).exec();
    }
}


const Users = {
    type: new GraphQLList(UserType),
    description: 'Get all users',
    resolve(root) {
        const companies = UserModel.find({ deleted: false }).exec();
        if (!companies) {
            throw new Error('Error getting users.')
        }
        return companies;   
    }
}

export default {
    User,
    Users
}
```

**./graphql/Company/types.js**

```
import { 
    GraphQLObjectType, 
    GraphQLInputObjectType,
    GraphQLNonNull,
    GraphQLID,
    GraphQLList,
    GraphQLString, 
    GraphQLInt, 
    GraphQLBoolean 
} from 'graphql';

 import { GraphQLLong } from '../scalars';

 import { UserType } from '../User/types';

 import { NodeInterface } from '../interfaces';

 import UserModel from '../../models/User';

 const fields = {
    _id: {
        type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLID)
    },
    name: {
        type: GraphQLString
    },
    ein: {
        type: GraphQLString
    },
    users: {
        type: new GraphQLList(UserType),
        resolve(company) {
            const { _id } = company;
            return UserModel.find({ companyId: _id }).exec();
        }
    }
 };

 export const CompanyType = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'Company',
    description: 'Company',
    interface: NodeInterface,
    fields: fields
 })
```

**./graphql/Company/queries.js**

```
import { GraphQLNonNull, GraphQLID, GraphQLList } from 'graphql';

import { CompanyType, CompanyInputType } from './types';
import CompanyModel from '../../models/Company';

const Company = {
    type: CompanyType,
    description: 'Get single company',
    args: {
        id: {
            name: 'id',
            type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLID)
        }
    },
    resolve(root, params) {

        params.deleted = false;

        return CompanyModel.find(params).exec();
    }
}


const Companies = {
    type: new GraphQLList(CompanyType),
    description: 'Get all companies',
    resolve(root) {
        const companies = CompanyModel.find({ deleted: false }).exec();
        if (!companies) {
            throw new Error('Error getting companies.')
        }
        return companies;   
    }
}

export default {
    Company,
    Companies
}
```

**./graphql/interfaces.js**

```
import { 
    GraphQLInterfaceType,
    GraphQLNonNull, 
    GraphQLID 
} from 'graphql';


const NodeInterface = new GraphQLInterfaceType({
    name: 'Node',
    fields: {
        id: {
            type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLID)
        }
    },
    resolveType: (source) => {

        return source.__type;
    }
});

export default NodeInterface;
```

**./graphql/schema.js**

```
import { GraphQLObjectType, GraphQLSchema } from 'graphql';
import queries from './queries';
import mutations from './mutations';


export default new GraphQLSchema({
    query: new GraphQLObjectType({
        name: 'Query',
        fields: queries
    }),
    mutation: new GraphQLObjectType({
        name: 'Mutation',
        fields: mutations
    })
});
```

**./graphql/queries.js**

```
import {
    GraphQLObjectType,
    GraphQLNonNull,
    GraphQLID
} from 'graphql';

import { NodeInterface } from './interfaces';
import CompanyQueries from './Company/queries';
import UserQueries from './User/queries';

const RootQuery = new GraphQLObjectType({

    name: 'RootQuery',
    description: 'The root query',
    fields: {
        viewer: {
            type: NodeInterface,
            resolve(source, args, context) {
                return { result: "VIEWER!" };
            }
        },
        node: {
            type: NodeInterface,
            args: {
                id: {
                    type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLID)
                }
            },
            resolve(source, args, context, info) {
                return { result: "NODE QUERY" };
            }
        }
    }
});

export default {
    RootQuery,
    ...CompanyQueries,
    ...UserQueries
}
```

**./server.js**

```
import express from 'express';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import morgan from 'morgan';
import graphqlHTTP from 'express-graphql';

import schema from './graphql/schema';

// set up example server
const app = express();
app.set('port', (process.env.API_PORT || 3001));


// logger
app.use(morgan('dev')); 

// parse body
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use('/graphql', graphqlHTTP({
    schema: schema,
    graphiql: true,
    pretty: true
}));

const mongoUri = process.env.MONGO_URI || 'mongodb://localhost/testdb';

mongoose.set('debug', true);

mongoose.connect(mongoUri, {
    useMongoClient: true,
});

export default app;
```

The RootQuery is not being added to Schema. In fact I'm getting this error:

```
Error: Query.RootQuery field type must be Output Type but got: undefined.
```

Conceptually I don't know how to fix this code:

a) I don't know how to add that RootQuery to my query, and I don't know if I need to keep my other queries to my server (as Relay basically relies on node queries).

b) I cannot also see how my RootQuery will discover the object type and return it at the `return source.__type`. I've added that piece of code but I don't know how or where the given type will fill up this field.

Although I'm understanding a little of GraphQL, it seems that I don't have yet the fundamentals on how to build the Relay required root query (not to talk about the paginators, but this is my next step once I solve that).

Comment: Can you show scalars.js ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears to be

```
import queries from './queries';

new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'Query',
    fields: queries
}),
```

```
const RootQuery = new GraphQLObjectType({
    …
});

export default {
    RootQuery,
    …
};
```

The `queries` that you pass as the fields for the `Query` type is an object of types, not an object of field configurations. They are missing `type` and `resolve` properties, as the error message complains.